# How to move reusable code from Play Framework template to separate template (Scala)?

Tags: scala, templates, playframework-2.0

I have this reusable code in the template and it works fine.

```
@headers(page: String,site:Site, user: User) = @{
    page match {
        case "home" => Map(
            "title" -> "Welcome",
            "description" -> "Welcome to our site")
        case "profile" => Map(
            "title" -> user.name + "-" site.name,
            "description" -> "Hello" + user.name)
    }
}
```

Now I want to move it to separate template and include it in main template.
If I put it in separate file like this

```
@(page: String,site:Site, user: User) = page match {
        case "home" => Map(
            "title" -> "Welcome",
            "description" -> "Welcome to our site")
        case "profile" => Map(
            "title" -> user.name + "-" site.name,
            "description" -> "Hello" + user.name)
    }
```

When I try to get data from it in main template

```
@templates.layout_headers("home", user, site)("title") I've got error
```

> does not take parameters
>   complaining on

```
("title")
```

part. How this can be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Your template does not accept a title parameter. You can think of twirl templates as normal scala functions. A template named `layout_header.scala.html` containing the signature `@(page: String, site:Site, user: User)` is equivalent to

```
def layout_header(page: String, site: Site, user: User): play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable
```

Now you are trying to call that function like `layout_headers(user, site)("title")` which is obviously wrong because of two points. Firstly the parameter `page` is missing. Secondly the function does not accept a `title` parameter.

As you are not using a `title` in `layout_headers`, just ditch it from your call and add the `page` parameter:

```
@templates.layout_headers(page, user, site)
```

If you need `title` to be available in your template, add it to the signature:

```
@(page: String, site:Site, user: User, title: String) = page match {
  ...
}
```

which then will be called as

```
@templates.layout_headers(page, user, site, "Some title")
```

Comment: Sorry, there was page parameter, fixed my question. The problem is: my child layout should return Map and with this ("title") part I try to get value from a Map, I don't need it to add to input parameter

Comment: Well this won't work, instead of a twirl template you could use a regular scala function. What are you trying to achieve? Displaying a header on all of your pages?

Comment: I want to display different header for some pages.